# Convert date time string to only date get

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript have this string

```
2011-10-10T14:48:00-06:00
```

How do I create a date that doesn't have the timezone? I want to remove the `-06:00`.

Comment: Also, what about the T in between?

Comment: Dates don't have a timezone. When parsing strings with a timezone, it will be used to generate a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) representing the equivalent UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way:

```
const dt = "2011-10-10T14:48:00-06:00"
dt.slice(0, 19); // "2011-10-10T14:48:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript always creates a Date object with the current server (or browser) timezone. I.e. if I do `new Date("2011-10-10T14:48:00-06:00")` on my laptop, I have a `Mon Oct 10 2011 22:48:00 GMT+0200` as a result. But if I do `new Date("2011-10-10T14:48:00")` I have `Mon Oct 10 2011 14:48:00 GMT+0200` as a result. Thus, my Date object always has a timezone set to my laptop's timezone, but the `-06:00` affects the interpretation of the string date during the parsing stage.

There is no way to affect this behavior except to set `TZ=<...>` environment variable (applies for Node.js only). JavaScript `Date` object doesn't expose any methods to work with the time zone.

If you need more sophisticated timezone handling, consider using [momentjs-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) package. But be aware it's quite huge and sometimes slow.

Comment: "*JavaScript always creates a Date object with the current server (or browser) timezone*" no it doesn't. Dates don't have a timezone, they're always UTC. The output of *Date.prototype.toString* does include the host local timezone, which is based on system settings. The Date itself doesn't know what timezone it's in.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this one code sample.

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();    
newdate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
```

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. It also use UTC values but presents the date as if it's local.